# Find most frequent item of a JS array with one loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created a function which finds the most frequent item of a JS array with two for loops and displays the item and how many times there is in the array. How can I do it with one loop?

```
var arr=[3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'a', 3, 'a', 2, 4, 9, 3];

//ta = times appeared / m = max / arrchar = array character
var ta = 1;
var m = 0;
var arrchar;

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
        for (var j=i; j<arr.length; j++)
        {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                 m++;
                if (ta<m)
                {
                  ta=m; 
                  arrchar = arr[i];
                }
        }
        m=0;
}
console.log(arrchar+"("+ta +")") ;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The magic word here is *hashtable*. If you create a Map of each item to a count, then you can look up increase and store the count in O(1), and you can also store the maxum count at the same time:

```
 let max = null, maxCount = -Infinity;
 const counts = new Map();

 for(const el of arr) {
   const count = (counts.get(el) || 0) + 1;
   counts.set(el, count);
   if(count > maxCount) {
      maxCount = count;
      max = el;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest approach is count occurrence of each element as sort them descending and get the first values

```js
var arr = [3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'a', 3, 'a', 2, 4, 9, 3];

let findMostFrequent = (arr) => {
  return [...arr.reduce((op, inp) => {
    op.set(inp, (op.get(inp) || 0) + 1)
    return op
  }, new Map())].sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])[0][0]
}


console.log(findMostFrequent(arr))
```

---

Single loop version

You can use an array as accumulator in reduce method, here first element is `Map` to keep track of values and it's occurrences and second element is to keep track of the `maxCount` and `maxValue`, change these values based on values in `Map`

```js
var arr = [3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'a', 3, 'a', 2, 4, 9, 3];

let findMostFrequent = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((op, inp) => {
    op[0].set(inp, (op[0].get(inp) || 0) + 1)
    if(op[0].get(inp) > op[1].maxCount){
      op[1].maxCount = op[0].get(inp)
      op[1].maxValue = inp
    }
    return op
  }, [new Map(), {maxCount:1, maxValue: arr[0]}])[1].maxValue
}


console.log(findMostFrequent(arr))
```

This further can be simplified by using two separate variable and only Map as accumulator so you need not to access values by index every time, look at the approach in Jhon's answer which uses two variable named `maxCount` and `max`

Comment: An optimal sort is O(n log n). Thats not really "one loop".

Comment: @JonasWilms added other version which does it with single loop only

Comment: Mr. downvoter leaving a comment will help me to learn more :)